# Understand the angular & in isolated scope and tits ()()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I wandering why when I'm passing method from outer scope to directive with isolated scope using '&' I need to call this method in directive with with double brackets ()().

It's looking like the function is returned with callThat() and then i need to call it with another ().

First function looks something like that:

```
function (b){return t(a,b)}
```

Some html:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="row" ng-controller='myController'>
    <my-directive call-that="myPassedMethod"></my-directive>
  </div>
</div>
```

My controller

```
app.controller('myController', function($scope){
  $scope.myPassedMethod = function(){
    console.log('War, war never changes');
  }
});
```

I've my directive:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      callThat : '&'
    },
    templateUrl: 'something_irrelevant.html',
    controller: function ($scope) {
      $scope.calledFromIrrelevantTemplate = function () {
        $scope.callThat()(); // why i need ()(); here?
      };

    }
  }
});
```

Could some one explain me this construction? 
(I'm not experienced JS dev, please use easy language).

Comment: `()()` would just be a double function call. kind of equivalent to `temp = $scope.callThat(); temp()`.

Comment: I also curious why someone down voted my question? What was wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you need the double function call is because you are passing your function like this:

```
<my-directive call-that="myPassedMethod"></my-directive>
```

You should change it to:

```
<my-directive call-that="myPassedMethod()"></my-directive>
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/xJnEEAGfrBXl5NXIIrZs?p=preview